# Maven Plugin fails with missing class javax/xml/bind/JAXBException even after adding jaxb-core, jaxb-api, jaxb-impl dependencies

Tags: java, maven

My pom contains:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

But when I run `mvn deploy`, it fails with:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   com.github.seanroy:lambda-maven-plugin:2.3.2:deploy-lambda (default)
>   on project California_GIS_Services: Execution default of goal
>   com.github.seanroy:lambda-maven-plugin:2.3.2:deploy-lambda failed: A
>   required class was missing while executing
>   com.github.seanroy:lambda-maven-plugin:2.3.2:deploy-lambda:
>   javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

Is there something different that needs to be done to get the plugin to use the compile dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by adding a dependency to the plug-in:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.seanroy</groupId>
            <artifactId>lambda-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            ....
        </plugin>
```